# Can't execute function call on X minutes more than once in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, nsthread

I tried to make function that will be invoked every minute (**without timer**).
When I run the app it executes after one minute and never again.
I probably miss something but can't find what?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:date];

    NSTimeInterval timeSinceLastSecond = date.timeIntervalSince1970 - floor(date.timeIntervalSince1970);
    NSTimeInterval timeToNextMinute = (60 - dateComponents.second) - timeSinceLastSecond;

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(timeToNextMinute * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [self myFunction];

    });

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: am little confused! isn't dispatch_after defers the execution by time, not repeat at intervals ?

Comment: Right @JeslyVarghese just make a recursive call by using same dispatch handler in the function itself

Comment: @channi: ah! recursion.. Is it good? for something that can be achieved by NSTimer. A stack of delayed function call dreads me. Is there any control over execution then ?

Comment: @JeslyVarghese No NSTimer is much better option for this scenario but in question user "1100" specifically said that without timer so i thought of giving him an alternative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
    [self executeEveryOneMinute];
    return YES:
 }

 - (void)executeEveryOneMinute
 {
    [self myFunction]
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(60 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [self executeEveryOneMinute];

    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void runBlockInSeconds(dispatch_block_t block,int seconds) {

    //initial block
    block();

    //get current time
    struct timespec startPopTime ;
    gettimeofday((struct timeval*)&startPopTime, NULL);

    //trim the time
    startPopTime.tv_sec -= (startPopTime.tv_sec % seconds);
    startPopTime.tv_sec +=seconds;

    dispatch_time_t time = dispatch_walltime(&startPopTime, 0);

    dispatch_block_t __block afterBlock = ^(void) {
        block();

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, NSEC_PER_SEC * seconds), dispatch_get_main_queue(), afterBlock);
    };

    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), afterBlock);
}
```